# Deducing the type of c++ derived object from list of base pointers

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-deduction, return-type-deduction

I have a list of abstract class's pointers. The class is defined as follows, and i need to get the derived class from the contained object later on:

```
class IContainer {
  class TT;

public:
  ~IContainer() = default;

  auto& GetType() const {
    return *this;
  }

  virtual IContainer& GetThis() = 0;

};

template <typename Type>
class Container : public IContainer {
  using TT = Type;

public:
  Container(const Type& var) : var_{var} {}
  Type GetVar2() { return var_; }
  Type var_{};

  // This method is returning IContainer, yet am expecting derived one
  Container<Type>& GetThis() override {
    std::cout << "name: " << typeid(TT).name() << std::endl;
    return static_cast<Container<Type>&>(*this);
  }
};
```

I use it like

```
  std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<IContainer>> data;
  int x{5};
  using Type = Container<decltype(x)>;
  data["val1"] = std::make_shared<Type>(x);
  double y{2.3};
  data["val2"] = std::make_shared<Container<decltype(y)>>(y);

  auto& ixptr = data.at("val1");
  auto& xptr = ixptr->GetThis();

  xptr.GetVar2(); //NOT WORKING
```

In fact I want to access `_var`.
How to do that with c++ 14?
INFO: I get this error message:

```
error: ‘class IContainer’ has no member named ‘GetVar2
```

Comment: This can’t work. What is this code supposed to do if the key is supplied by the user instead of hard-coded (i.e. `ixptr = data.at(user_supplied_value)`)?

Comment: They key will not be supplied. This is only for demo. At the end i will have `for (const aut auto& datum : data)`. You can also think of it as simple std::vector

Comment: That’s my point. You have a *static* type. It can’t be variable: what you want implies that in subsequent iterations in your `for` loop the static type of the loop variable would be different. That’s not supported in C++.

Comment: In fact I wanted to have a kind of c++ 17 std::variant.

Comment: But `std::variant` *also can’t do this* (nor can `std::any`). It avoids this problem via its use of `std::visit`. You can of course implement either type (or close enough) in C++14, or use the existing Boost implementations.

Comment: Why not put in a function in the derived classes to report on the type of derived class it is? Like just have it return a value representing the type, and in the function just have return 0 for derived class type 0 and return 1 for derived class type 1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` variable is a `std::map` holding elements of type `std::pair<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<IContainer>>`, so the type of `ixptr` gets deduced as `std::shared_ptr<IContainer>`, thus `ixptr->` returns an `IContainer*` pointer, and calling `GetThis()` on that pointer returns an `IContainer&` regardless of how descendant classes override `GetThis()`. So the type of `xptr` gets deduced as `IContainer&`, and since `IContainer` does not have a `GetVar2()` method, that is why `xptr.GetVar2()` fails to compile.

`dynamic_cast` can be used to solve this, eg:

```cpp
auto &ixptr = data.at(...);
auto &xptr = ixptr->GetThis();

auto *xptr_int = dynamic_cast<Container<int>*>(&xptr);
if (xptr_int)
{
    int var2 = xptr_int->GetVar2();
    ...
}
```

This logic can also be applied to your `for` loop:

```cpp
for (const auto &datum : data)
{
    auto &xptr = datum.second->GetThis();
    auto *xptr_int = dynamic_cast<Container<int>*>(&xptr);
    if (xptr_int)
    {
        int var2 = xptr_int->GetVar2();
        ...
    }
}
```

`xptr_int` will be non-`nullptr` for `"val1"`, but will be `nullptr` for `"val2"`, since `Container<int>` and `Container<double>` are separate and unrelated types.

Comment: Thanks, but how to use `var2` outside `if(xptr)`. Seems i would need code dupliction

Comment: Simply move the declaration of `var2` above the `if`, and give it a sensible default value for when `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr`, eg: `int var2 = 0; if (xptr_int) { var2 = xptr_int->GetVar2(); } // use var2 as needed ...`